# php session displaying previous session values

Tags: php, javascript, session, session-variables

I am calling a console application from php which gives me some output. I have to display the output in a div after the console application is executed. I have passed the output from the console application as a SESSION to another page to display it. I have used ajax and javascript in my webpage too which make it more complicated. Now when I print the output the output in the div is the previous value of the SESSION.My code is as follows:

The main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

                    $('#file').live('change', function()    
                    { 
                    $("#preview").html('');
                    $("#preview").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
                    $("#imageform").ajaxForm(
                    {
                    target: '#preview'
                    }).submit();

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function myfunction()
                    {
                    $("#display").html('');
                    $("#display").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
                    $("#retrieveimageform").ajaxForm(
                    {
                    target: '#display'
                    }).submit();

                     $('#tags').html('<?php include 'Tagsdisplay.php';?>');  
 %I want to include this only after it goes through the retrieveimage1.php page
 where the console application is called and the session is created but this is
 not happening the tags div is shown before the console application is called 
 and the other results are displayed on the display div
                     $('#tags').show();
                    };


                    </script>

        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="maindiv">
                <div id="banner">
                <?php
                include 'Header.php';

                ?>
                 </div>
                <div id="wrapper">

                        <div id="imageupload">
                    <form action="uploadimage.php" method="post"
                         enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageform">
                         <label for="file">Upload your image:</label>
                       <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>

                    </form>
                        </div>
                       <div id='preview'>  
                        </div>
                    <div id='tags'>

                    </div>

                       <div class="clear"></div>

                    <form action="retrieveimage1.php" method="post"
                           id="retrieveimageform">

                       ................................   

                         <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" id="btnSearch" onclick="myfunction()">

                    </form>
     <div id="display"></div>

                 </div>
```

The retrieveimage.php where the console app is called and session is created:

```
          session_start();
          $start_time=  microtime(true);
        if (isset($_SESSION['img']))
        {   
                $image=$_SESSION['img'];
                $_SESSION['coarselbl1']=" ";
                $_SESSION['coarselbl2']=" ";
                $_SESSION['coarselbl3']=" ";
                $_SESSION['finelbl1']=" ";
                $_SESSION['finelbl2']=" ";
                $_SESSION['finelbl3']=" ";
                $_SESSION['finelbl4']=" ";
                $_SESSION['category']=" ";
                    if($_POST['cat']=='handbag')
                            {
                                 $_SESSION['category']="Bag";
                                 $cwt=$_POST["slider1"];
                                $fwt=$_POST["slider2"];
                                $twt=$_POST["slider3"];
                                $swt=$_POST["slider4"];

                                $addr="handbags31_fourth.exe $image $cwt $fwt $swt $twt";
                                  exec($addr,$data);

                                  $_SESSION['coarselbl1']=$data[2];
                                  $_SESSION['coarselbl2']=$data[3];
                                  $_SESSION['coarselbl3']=$data[4];
                   }
```

The TagsDisplay.php where the tags are displayed:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        echo $_SESSION['category']."<br/>";
   if($_SESSION['category']=="Bag")
    {
        echo "Coarse Color:   ".$_SESSION['coarselbl1'].",".$_SESSION['coarselbl2'].",".$_SESSION['coarselbl3']."<br/>";
        unset($_SESSION['coarselbl1']);
        unset($_SESSION['coarselbl2']);
        unset($_SESSION['coarselbl3']);


    }


?>
```

The problem here is when I click the search button the myfunction is called and the tags div is displayed before the display div and the value printed are the previous session value. I want the tag div to come only after the display div is shown and the new session are assigned. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why you need to unset each and every session?

Comment: I unset it because I though it would solve the problem but it did not as it was taking previous values of the session.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the jquery line

```
$('#tags').html('<?php include 'Tagsdisplay.php';?>');
```

to this:

```
$('#tags').html('<?php include "Tagsdisplay.php";?>');
```

(note the quotes) because you are not even including the file that unsets the previous session's values.

Comment: thanks but the problem is still not solved now the div is blank and as the div is displayed as soon as I click the button the session is not set yet. How can I change it so that only after the retrieveimage.php is called the tag div is displayed?

Comment: sorry it is not blank always I am getting the previous SESSIOn value displayed when I run it 2 3 times